# Grade Calculator Program in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to make a program that calculates the average of a list of grades. I have done my research and found some codes to compute the average of a list of numbers, but they only compute integers, which I consider not right.

This source code is from Sir Craig Estey. This is the program I am currently using, and I want to make some adjustments to it. If you input a list of 3 grades, 90, 90, 91, the result the program will give you is 90. So, what will I do to make it 90.33?

```
.data

    # NOTE/BUG: due to alignment issues put the .word directives _before_
    # the [variable length] .asciiz directives
size:       .word       0
to_store:   .word       0
sum:        .word       0
avg:        .word       0

size_prompt:    .asciiz "Enter number of elements: "
element_prompt: .asciiz "Enter an element: "
msg_space:      .asciiz " "

    .text
    .globl  main
main:

    # Prints prompt
    la      $a0,size_prompt
    addi    $v0,$0,4
    syscall

    # Gets input from user
    addi    $v0,$0,5
    syscall
    sw      $v0,size

    addi    $t0,$0,0                # Initialise i = 0

    # Creates the list
    lw      $s0,size                # get array count
    addi    $t1,$0,4                # get 4
    mult    $s0,$t1                 # get count * 4
    mflo    $t2                     # get offset
    add     $a0,$t1,$t2
    addi    $v0,$0,9
    syscall

stack:
    beq     $t0,$s0,list_sum        # done with number input? if yes, fly

    # prompt user for list element
    la      $a0,element_prompt
    addi    $v0,$0,4
    syscall

    # read in element value
    addi    $v0,$0,5
    syscall
    sw      $v0,to_store
    lw      $t5,to_store

    # push element to stack
    addi    $sp,$sp,-4
    sw      $t5,0($sp)

    addi    $t0,$t0,1           # advance array index
    j       stack

    # get sum of array elements
list_sum:
    beq     $s0,0,average       # at end? if yes, fly
    lw      $t6,sum             # get previous sum
    lw      $t7,0($sp)          # get next array element value
    addi    $sp,$sp,4           # advance array pointer
    add     $t6,$t7,$t6         # sum += array[i]
    sw      $t6,sum             # store it
    addi    $s0,$s0,-1          # bump down the _count_
    j       list_sum

    # NOTE/BUG: in the list_sum loop above, s0 is being decremented, so when we
    # get here it is _always_ zero
average:
    lw      $t0,sum             # get the sum

    # print the sum
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$t0
    syscall

    # NOTE/FIX: restore the count value
    lw      $s0,size

    div     $t0,$s0             # divide by count
    mflo    $t0
    sw      $t0,avg             # store average

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_space
    syscall

    # print average
    lw      $a0,avg
    addi    $v0,$0,1
    syscall

exit:
    li      $v0,10              # exit program
    syscall
```

Comment: If you want two decimal places and don't want to mess with floating point, you can scale your numbers by 100 and adjust the printing.

Comment: You'll have to refine your requirements.  Use floating point is one answer, but is it the answer you're looking for?  However, floating point will give you an answer of 90.33333333333 instead of 90.33.

Comment: @Jester Thanks man. I could use that approach!

Comment: You should use the `$f` registers
`calculateAvg:
        lw $t0, total
        mtc1 $t0, $f2
        lw $t1, nrOfValues
        mtc1 $t1, $f4
        div.s $f12, $f2, $f4
        swc1 $f12, average
`
`average` is `.float`

Comment: The DIV instruction will only ever produce integer results, it's working as designed. To use floating point you need to use the floating point registers.